# gitlab repository in external hdd

Tags: github, gitlab

I have hosted gitlab in ubuntu and my project repositories saved in external hard disk After unmounting external hard disk i need to reconfigure gitlab each and evrey repository in HDD. Is it possible to save repositories permanently after remounting of external HDD.

Comment: Define "reconfigure". If you're just storing your local repos on the HDD, there shouldn't be any issue. You mention "hosted gitlab", does this mean you're running your own git server?

Comment: yes i am hosted own gitlab server i want to store my repositories on my external HDD permanently when i mount and remount the external HDD.

Comment: please provide steps and solution